# Android Swipe View with Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, swipeview

How can I add a tab underline that follows the swipe like in the google play store. For now the tab line only moves when I finish the swipe. Also how can i add a background between fragments while swiping.

Comment: I already have Swipe With Tabs implemented. I needed a way to hide show a separator background between fragments while swiping.